# Mongoose aggregate get total numbers of members in a group model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a model like this :

```
var field = {
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    pic : {type: String, default: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/abstract/', writable: true},
    thumb : {type: String, default: 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/', writable: true},

    name: {type: String},
    description: {type: String},
    isPublic: {type: Boolean, default: true},
    members: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Member'}],
}
```

Im using this code below to get the total count of the `Member`'s ID in members field.

```
Group.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id:req.params.group_id}},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$members',
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }}
], function (err, count) {
    res.send(count);
});
```

But it returns and empty array `[]` how do I get the proper count?

Thanks.

Comment: Mongoose does not "autocast" to `ObjectId` in aggregation pipelines. You need to cast it yourself, else your `$match` matches nothing. Been asked before, let me search for the duplicate(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use $match with mongoose and the aggregation framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551387/cant-use-match-with-mongoose-and-the-aggregation-framework)

Comment: Also on [issue #1399](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1399)

Comment: So assuming that I got the working `{$match}` will this return the total number of `members`? Thanks.@BlakesSeven

Comment: Lengthy related [Mongoose Aggregation does not Filter by Input Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655476/mongoose-aggregation-does-not-filter-by-input-date/35663467#35663467)

Comment: I suppose you have "two" questions really, being your actual question and the main reason for the empty result.

Comment: See also [Querying Interal Array Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722850/querying-internal-array-size-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose does not "autocast" to `OjectId` or any other schema type within the aggregation pipeline. So your operation returns nothing since it matches nothing.

Also, that would not be the approach to counting members of an array.

Better to use the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) option instead to count array members per document:

```js
Group.aggregate([
    { "$match": { _id: ObjectId(req.params.group_id) }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": { "$sum": { "$size": "$members" } }
    }}
], function (err, count) {
    res.send(count);
});
```

And `$group` with the `_id` for the appropriate roll-up, or `null` as used here for all items in the collection.

If you wanted the "count of each distinct member" then you would process with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) across document(s) instead:

```js
Group.aggregate([
    { "$match": { _id: ObjectId(req.params.group_id) }},
    { "$unwind": "$members" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$members",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
], function (err, count) {
    res.send(count);
});
```

Comment: { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": { "$sum": { "$size": "$members" } }
    }} 

returns 

{ name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'exception: invalid operator \'$size\'',
  errmsg: 'exception: invalid operator \'$size\'',
  code: 15999,
  ok: 0 }

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx Which MongoDB server version do you have? `$size` has been supported since MongoDB 2.6, so it must be old. Variate on processing with `$unwind` and `null` or `$_id` even in the `$group` `_id` key.

Comment: Oooh I was using 2.4.9 I should upgrade.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx Yes you should. `$unwind` is your only approach pre 2.6. Note that just `{ "$project": { "count": { "$size": "$members" } } }` works just fine ( where supported ) if you are only doing this per document and not actually "grouping" anything. I would also advise to keep the "count" in your document via [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) when adding to arrays

Comment: I think the `$inc` approach will be fine coz everytime I get a group I always needed the count. Great advice +1